# How to import JAVA packages in cmd?

Tags: java

This is the first time I am compiling a program, and it doesn't seem to be working out.  Looks like some packages are not being located - so for this question, I'll just focus on one:

Steps I've take so far:

**1)** setting up the System Variable Path to include java

[image]

**2)** in CMD.exe:  `jar tf log4j.jar`  I did this to make sure it includes **log4j.Logger**  and it does.

[image]

**3)** I Shift+rightclick and open command prompt from this folder:

[image]

**4)** Then I enter `javac TNT.java` and i get the following error (along with others):
[image]

Any thoughts?

I set the classpath to the same folders with `set classpath = "name of folder"` no change...
***edit***
***5)*** have also tried
`javac -cp jdkbindirectory;jrebindirectory;theabovefolder TNT.java`

I get this:
[image]blahblahblah

Comment: Add the class path when you compile, `-cp ...`

Comment: hi thanks for responding, i tried javac TNT.java -cp "folderdirectory" and nothing
i tried -cp "folderdirectory" javac TNT.java and nothing

i get javac: invalid flag: -
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: maybe time to use right tool, eg [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org)

Comment: @rkosegi it’s quite a good thing to understand how compiling from the command line should be done

Comment: @JoakimDanielson
at this point I've also tried:
javac -cp "bin directory";"TNTfolder" TNT.java

i get same result

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, you need to specify the class path as the path to the .jar itself. I don’t think it’s enough to specify the directory alone.

Comment: @stephancasas hi stephan, I tried your approach
set classpath = %PATH% (this includes jdk and jre bins directories) ; foldername\log4j.jar
then
javac TNT.java

got same error of not finding the logger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't set the classpath using an environment variable as it is bad practice. What if you accidentally change it later for a different project and your current project breaks?

When including classes in the classpath, you can include the path of the root of the package of the class, as in the folder that contains the folders in the package structure. However, when you're including a jar in your classpath, you need to put the entire path of the jar file (relative to the current working directory) all the way up to the *jarname.jar*.

Also, remember that by default, java looks in the current working directory and uses that as its default classpath. However, as soon as you specify a classpath it no longer does that automatically for you. Be sure that you're including your current directory in your classpath as well.

Finally, be sure to surround the classpath in quotes otherwise java might think its a part of another argument.

I would try this:

```
javac -cp "./;log4j.jar" TNT.java
```

And then to execute the class file:

```
java -cp "./;log4j.jar" TNT
```

Hope this works, good luck!

Comment: this is amazingly helpful!

Comment: @jayykaa I'm very glad I could help :)